# Serial port reading print output from a machine

Tags: java, serial-port, thermal-printer

I'm reading print output from a money counter machine through a serial port using Java.

This is data that the machine sends when it finishes counting:

[Machine print output](https://justpaste.it/1u9kb)

[Machhine print out file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fe33f036e6accc0347758309d798a68320220526074736/9f96c0)

And this is how it looks when its printed on a thermal POS printer:

[image]

Its not the same banknote(different S/N) on both outputs, but you will probably understand what I'm saying.

I successfully extracted all the count data from this output, but my problem is with serial number of the banknote.

My question is how can I get the picture of ***the serial number*** to show on my screen, like it is shown when printed?

Is there any protocol that the printer uses to print the picture that I can use in Java?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Here is the explanation I got, but I'm still not sure how to get the picture in JAVA.

[image]

[image]

EDIT 2:

I used the following code to get the byte array from Serial port and convert it to binaryString. I used one of the bytes that represents the new line and inserted the new line each time that value is found.

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String s1 = new String();

            if (serialPortEvent.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE) {
                return;
            }
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[comPort.bytesAvailable()];
            int numRead = comPort.readBytes(readBuffer, readBuffer.length);
            //System.out.println("Read " + numRead + " bytes.");

            for (Byte b : readBuffer) {

                //image is more than 500 bytes, all other data is less than 500
                if (numRead <= 500) {
                    break;
                }

                s1 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');

                //new line byte, everytime it shows up I add a new 
                line
                if (s1.equals("01000101")) {
                    System.out.println();
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.print(s1);
```

I store everything in a String and print it out after I receive all the data. Here is the system out of the s1 String pasted in a text editor.

[image: binaryString image]

I dont know how well it can be seen in the image, but this is a copied String where picture is made from zeros and ones and you can clearly see the serial number.

My question now is how can I convert this to an image file?

Comment: Read the manual of the machine. Perhaps that extra data at the end is image data.

Comment: Extra data is the image data, but I don't know how to show it as an image. There is nothing about this in the manual of the machine.

Comment: It might be an idea, instead of pasting the result onto an external site, to save it with `FileOutputStream` to a file and post a link to it. That way, the actual data are not in question

Comment: Also I'm puzzled as to why textual info has been made into an image in one place and not in others.

Comment: It's not Java, but why not give these tools a try? [receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools](https://github.com/receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools), [kunif/EscPosUtils](https://github.com/kunif/EscPosUtils)

Comment: I added new information in the post.

Comment: @g00se Machine scans the S/N of banknote and does OCR of the scan and sends that OCR data in text form and that same data in picture format. 
I uploaded the file in the post.

Comment: I see. That looks annoyingly proprietary in format. What is the hardware model btw?

Comment: It is a Hyundai Mib SB-9 machine. I posted some pictures explaining how to convert to picture, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: This is quite a fascinating mystery. How are you getting on?

Comment: Looking at this page, is there a mode or model that sends image data and recognition results to the PC? Why not ask the vendor for those materials? [SB-9 Professional 2 Pocket Mixed Denomination Value Counter](https://www.hyundaimib.com/products/sb-9/)

Comment: I'm sort of hoping that the data you posted is a 'dummy' that shows a striped pattern. If that's the case, I could have something ;)

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I didn't get the chance to work on this until the last few days.
I managed to get the byte array from the com port and convert it to binaryString.
I'm not sure how to get the picture from the String that I got.
Please see the original question, as I will edit it with new data.